# Centering the home/homeasup and action menu in an appcompat actionbar

Tags: android-layout, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

seems like I am the only one on SO with such problem. Why, android, why ?... 
have a look at the image. Only the title is centered (phew). The other two items... help!

[image]

here is the relevant xml mojo

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"                       
android:id="@+id/dl_base"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    tools:context="com.farmdog.farmdog.HelperActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_topbottom"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/appbar_padding_topbottom"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

and the styles:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark wont work on API level < 21 -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/mainBkgndHard</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/appTextColor</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonTheme</item>
    <!-- attempt taking actionbar shadow away -->
    <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/appTextColor</item>
    <item name="titleTextColor">@color/appTextColor</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/appTextColor</item>
    <item name="android:layout_centerVertical">true</item>
</style>




<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorActionBar</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set toolbar paddingTop and paddingBottom. You should remove them. I hope it will help resolve your problem.